Can I get LLM optimized output using WolframAlpha function in Mathematica?
Can I get LLM optimized output using WolframAlpha function in Mathematica? I want to use simple text output from Wolfram Alpha withoud complex pods. I know that this is available by API, but I didn/t find the right way for Mathematica.
Link to the doc: https://products.wolframalpha.com/llm-api/documentation
